# How to start twisted's reactor from ipython

Tags: twisted, ipython

I need to start a twisted'reactor from within ipython in a way that allows to go on interacting. Ipython's man page has references to twisted but I couldn't understand the way I should proceed. Documentation references IPython.kernel.twistedutil so that my impression is that it should be a standard solution...  Thanks in advance

sandro
*:-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410670-integrating-twisted-reactor-with-ipython/

This will start the Twisted reactor in a thread alongside IPython's main thread.  You should be able to access the Twisted thread from IPython.

Another possible solution would be to start a manhole ["Service"](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/core/howto/application.html) alongside your Twisted application in a `.tac` file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import thread

from twisted.internet import reactor, defer

# This usualy raises Unhandled Error
# exceptions.ValueError: signal only works in main thread
thread.start_new(reactor.run, ())

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def check():
    print "It works!"
    yield

reactor.callFromThread(check)
```