# Running twisted reactor in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, twisted

I'm aware this is normally done with twistd, but I'm wanting to use iPython to test out code 'live' on twisted code.

[How to start twisted's reactor from ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673375/how-to-start-twisteds-reactor-from-ipython) asked basically the same thing but the first solution no longer works with current ipython/twisted, while the second is also unusable (thread raises multiple errors).

https://gist.github.com/kived/8721434 has something called TPython which purports to do this, but running that seems to work except clients never connect to the server (while running the same clients works in the python shell).

Do I *have* to use Conch Manhole, or is there a way to get iPython to play nice (probably with _threadedselect).

For reference, I'm asking using ipython 5.0.0, python 2.7.12, twisted 16.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async code in general can be troublesome to run in a live interpreter. It's best just to run an async script in the background and do your iPython stuff in a separate interpreter. You can intercommunicate using files or TCP. If this went over your head, that's because it's not always simple and it might be best to avoid the hassle of possible.

However, you'll be happy to know there is an awesome project called `crochet` for using Twisted in non-async applications. It truly is one of my favorite modules and I'm shocked that it's not more widely used (you can change that ;D though). The `crochet` module has a `run_in_reactor` decorator that runs a Twisted reactor in a separate thread managed by `crochet` itself. Here is a quick class example that executes requests to a Star Wars RESTFul API, then stores the JSON response in a list.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json

from twisted.internet import defer, task
from twisted.web.client import getPage

from crochet import run_in_reactor, setup as setup_crochet
setup_crochet()

class StarWarsPeople(object):
    people_id = [_id for _id in range(1, 89)]
    people = []

    @run_in_reactor
    def requestPeople(self):
        """
        Request Star Wars JSON data from the SWAPI site.
        This occurs in a Twisted reactor in a separate thread.
        """
        for _id in self.people_id:
            url = 'http://swapi.co/api/people/{0}'.format(_id).encode('utf-8')
            d = getPage(url)
            d.addCallback(self.appendJSON)

    def appendJSON(self, response):
        """
        A callback which will take the response from the getPage() request, 
        convert it to JSON, then append it to self.people, which can be 
        accessed outside of the crochet thread.
        """
        response_json = json.loads(response.decode('utf-8'))
        #print(response_json)    # uncomment if you want to see output
        self.people.append(response_json)
```

Save this in a file (example: `swapi.py`), open iPython, import the newly created module, then run a quick test like so:

```
from swapi import StarWarsPeople
testing = StarWarsPeople()
testing.requestPeople()

from time import sleep
for x in range(5):
    print(len(testing.people))
    sleep(2)
```

As you can see it runs in the background and stuff can still occur in the main thread. You can continue using the iPython interpreter as you usually do. You can even have a manhole running in the background for some cool hacking too!

## References

- https://crochet.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.0/introduction.html#crochet-use-twisted-anywhere

Comment: This is basically what I'm already doing in my 'real' app, running twisted in a separate thread from UI. Thanks for the crochet link, but I've always figured its more suited for web WSGI stuff, and where I need to emulate blocking behaviour I'm now trying out inlineCallbacks/yield (which seems to do the same as wait_for).

Comment: Crochet isnt just for web stuff. You didn't provide a use case so I arbitrarily picked something and web requests were the choice :D. I probably shouldve put an example of ``wait_for`` but at the time I didn't know the context of your problem

Comment: Oh I didn't mean to imply it was only for web. I understand it as most useful for stuff that MUST block (wsgi, sqlalchemy), as opposed to a live interpreter that is already async to begin with (or GUI toolkits like kivy which are inherently frame driven)

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer the question I thought I had, it does answer (sort of) the question I posted. Embedding ipython works in the sense that you get access to business objects with the reactor running.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.endpoints import serverFromString
from myfactory import MyFactory

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        server = serverFromString(reactor, 'tcp:12345')
        server.list(MyFactory(self))
        def interact():
            import IPython
            IPython.embed()
        reactor.callInThread(interact)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myclass = MyClass()
    reactor.run()
```

Call the above with `python myclass.py` or similar.

Comment: This is not the answer you want though. Once you stop this reactor, you will not be able to restart it (this is a design choice in Twisted that cannot be "fixed"). Also you wont be able type in your ipython unless you stop the twisted reactor.

Comment: I haven't found a use-case for stopping the reactor yet though. And I can certainly type in my ipython (and continue playing with the business objects) as the shell is in a separate thread. My main use-case which this solves is that I can call MyClass methods and inspect what they return.

Comment: For inspecting objects and outputs I'd recommend the Python debugger as opposed to this method. You could put ``pdb.set_trace()`` inside your scripts or you could start from the debugger by ``ipython -m of script.py`` then place break points as needed before the reactor runs

Comment: That's good for debugging, but at this point I'm experimenting more than anything, and I find ipython suitable (well, familiar)