# How to run twisted webapps within their own threads and not using twistd

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I have a somewhat rich python application and do not want to restructure it just for the sake of exposing some http end-points.  I simply want to expose them via a set of threads that listen via http on those ports.

There are a couple of questions that are pertinent: but they are quite old and are not exactly what I am looking for:

- [How to start twisted's reactor from ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673375/how-to-start-twisteds-reactor-from-ipython)
- [Twisted application without twistd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610489/twisted-application-without-twistd)

What would be a "modern" approach and that would involve simply kicking off threads - or even better entries from a `threadpool` - for incorporating `twisted` into the existing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/itamarst/crochet

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
Do a DNS lookup using Twisted's APIs.
"""
from __future__ import print_function

# The Twisted code we'll be using:
from twisted.names import client

from crochet import setup, wait_for
setup()


# Crochet layer, wrapping Twisted's DNS library in a blocking call.
@wait_for(timeout=5.0)
def gethostbyname(name):
    """Lookup the IP of a given hostname.

    Unlike socket.gethostbyname() which can take an arbitrary amount of time
    to finish, this function will raise crochet.TimeoutError if more than 5
    seconds elapse without an answer being received.
    """
    d = client.lookupAddress(name)
    d.addCallback(lambda result: result[0][0].payload.dottedQuad())
    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Application code using the public API - notice it works in a normal
    # blocking manner, with no event loop visible:
    import sys
    name = sys.argv[1]
    ip = gethostbyname(name)
    print(name, "->", ip)
```